# Show $x = \frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$ if $z = x+iy$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm having trouble figuring out this question. $|z|=1$ and is on the contour which is a unit circle. Am I thinking about this too hard or is there a trick to doing this?

Comment: If $|z|=1$ then $\dfrac{1}{z}=z^*$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have for $0 \neq|z|=z\hat{z}=1$
$$
\frac{1}{z}z=z\frac{1}{z}=1
$$
as well as:
$$
\hat{z}z=z\hat{z}=1
$$
Since the inverse is unique in $\mathbb{C}^*$, we can conclude that $\hat{z}=\frac{1}{z}$. Now we subsitute:
$$
\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})=\frac{1}{2}(z+\hat{z})=\frac{1}{2}(x+iy+x-iy)=\frac{1}{2}2x=x
$$
Edit: Also an easy way to see the important identity is: $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\hat{z}}{\hat{z}z}=\frac{\hat{z}}{1}=\hat{z}$

Comment: You have a $y$ that should be an $x$.